# How to solve create task error in c#

Tags: c#, task

It is condition as below that I want to make task

Security options

1. Account : SYSTEM
2. Run whether user is logged on or not
3. run with highest privileges.

when I create task scheduler, exception occurs **(HRESULT : 0x80070005) 
E_ACESSDENIED**

```
    private void CreateTask()
    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
                            {
                                var newTask = ts.NewTask();
                                newTask.RegistrationInfo.Author = Environment.UserName;
                                newTask.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Crfs Bin Upload";
                                newTask.Principal.UserId = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value;
                                newTask.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
                                Trigger trigger = new DailyTrigger();
                                trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
                                trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                                trigger.Repetition.StopAtDurationEnd = false;
                                trigger.Enabled = true;

                                newTask.Settings.MultipleInstances = TaskInstancesPolicy.IgnoreNew;
                                newTask.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = true;
                                newTask.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = false;
                                newTask.Settings.AllowHardTerminate = false;
                                newTask.Settings.StartWhenAvailable = false;
                                newTask.Settings.RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = true;
                                newTask.Settings.IdleSettings.StopOnIdleEnd = false;
                                newTask.Settings.IdleSettings.RestartOnIdle = false;
                                newTask.Settings.Enabled = true;
                                newTask.Settings.Hidden = false;
                                newTask.Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle = false;
                                newTask.Settings.WakeToRun = false;
                                newTask.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
                                newTask.Settings.Priority = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;
                                newTask.Triggers.Add(trigger);
                                newTask.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe"));


                                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("NewTask", newTask);
                                MessageBox.Show("작업 스케줄러가 정상적으로 등록되었습니다.", "작업 스케줄러 등록", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("작업 스케줄러의 등록을 실패하였습니다.\r\n" + ex.Message, "작업 스케줄러 등록 실패", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access denied means you do not have permission to do this.

You cannot create a task to run as SYSTEM, unless you are an Administrator. You need to run this program from an elevated command prompt.